# can a Linux docker image run on Windows and Mac?

Tags: docker

I have a Java project that uses `OpenCV` and `tesseract` libraries, these libraries have native libraries (`libopencv`, `libopencv_java` and `libtesseract`). so these native libraries must be installed in target platforms (depending on the platform, Linux, Windows, or Mac), because of so many reasons like lack of knowledge of our customers, lack of pre-build native libraries (in my own system I had to build OpenCV, because I can not find a pre-build) and versions incompatibility I am thinking to create a custom Linux image and set up all required libraries + my Java application on this image and ship this docker image to our customers. but I am new to containers technology. I do not know whether it is possible or not. **does this solution work? if no, what is your recommendations** if it works it solves all my problems.

**update:**

is there any significant performance overhead in non-Linux Hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. Your customers will need an OCI compatible container runtime, like containerd, to run the images. Docker will of course work.

Comment: is there any significant performance overhead in non-Linux Hosts?

Comment: It depends if you're using Hyper-V or WSL2 for the windows part. Also depends if you're using bind-mounts and volumes or not. In some cases, you can expect nearly similar experiences. In other cases, Windows is less performant. It's hard to be general on this.